# $NL^2 = NDSPACE(\log^2n)$ is closed under complement

Tags: complexity-theory, space-complexity

- From Savitch's theorem we have $NL^2 \subseteq L^4$, which is deterministic and thus closed under complement.
- From Immerman–Szelepcsényi theorem we have $NL = coNL$.

Why then $NL^2 = coNL^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Immerman–Szelepcsényi theorem states that $\mathsf{NSPACE}(s(n))$ is closed under complementation whenever $s(n) \geq \log n$.